# How to trigger a window alert when an object is at a certain position within the page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with my code. I have created an object that moves by using the arrow keys. What I'm trying to achieve is that when the object reaches (is over) a certain position, specifically 500px down and 1100px right, it triggers a window alert without having to click a button.

Here is my code so far.

Thank you for your help.

```
<h2>Use arrow keys to move the train and reach the destination</h2>

<div>
<img id="trainpic" 
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/Icon_train. 
svg/2000px-Icon_train.svg.png" style="width:150px; height=120px;">
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div>
<img id="destination" 
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Kosovo_stub.svg" 
style="float: right; width:220px; height=190px;">
</div>


<script>

var train = $("#trainpic");
space = 0;

function checkSpace() {
if (space === 12)
{
$(train).animate({left: "0px"}, 'fast');
}
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
$(train).keydown;
switch(e.which) {

case 37:
$(train).animate({left: "-=100px"}, 'fast');
break;

case 38:
$(train).animate({top: "-=100px"}, 'fast');
break;

case 39:
$(train).animate({left: "+=100px"}, 'fast');
space++;
checkSpace();
break;

case 40:
$(train).animate({top: "+=100px"}, 'fast');
break;
};
});
</script>

<script>
var train = $("#trainpic");
if(($(train).css('left') == '-1100px')&& ($(train).css('top') == '-500px'))
{
   window.alert("You have reached your destination!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To trigger the alert you need to wrap your checking logic into a function and call it within the keydown event.

```
function CheckPosition(){
    var train = $("#trainpic");
    if(($(train).css('left') == '-1100px')&& ($(train).css('top') == '-500px'))
    {
       window.alert("You have reached your destination!");
    }
}
```

Then

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
     ...
     CheckPosition();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is some collision detection on the triggering object. That way you don't have to worry about exactly where the other object it, you just have to worry about them touching. Then you can call that in the callback of your animate.

```
function getPositions(box) {
  var $box = $(box);
  var pos = $box.position();
  var width = $box.width();
  var height = $box.height();
  return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
}

function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
  var x1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
  var x2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
  return x1[1] > x2[0] || x1[0] === x2[0] ? true : false;
}

function checkCollisions(){
  var box = $("#destination")[0];
  var pos = getPositions(box);

  var pos2 = getPositions(this);
  var horizontalMatch = comparePositions(pos[0], pos2[0]);
  var verticalMatch = comparePositions(pos[1], pos2[1]);            
  var match = horizontalMatch && verticalMatch;
  if (match) { window.alert("You have reached your destination!");}
}
```

Then add "checkCollisions" as a callback for all the instances of animate.

```
case 37:
$(train).animate({left: "-=100px"}, 'fast', checkCollisions);
break;
```

Comment: You can put them right after where your keydown function ends it'll be just fine there. Or right underneath your checkSpace() function.